# how to enable usb debugging in Galaxy S5 when screen broken?

Tags: samsung-mobile, galaxy

I want to reach data (contacts, sms...) in my galaxy s5 but the screen is broken and i am not able to enable usb debugging to control my phone using PC.

is there a way i can enable usb debugging via PC?

thank you

Comment: Have you tried using Samsung Kies?

Answer (score 1):

if you just need to access the data on your phone, you don't need to enable usb debugging. Just plug it into the USB port of your PC and access the file system of your phone. Get the photos, music etc you've stored on the phone.

Alternately if you can still use touch input use a HDMI adapter and connect your smartphone to a TV. The screen will be mirrored on your TV but your phone would still need to recognize touch inputs